# Apply different color depending of width size of a div?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to apply a different color to a div depending its width size.

My html is this

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="progress"></div>
      </div>
```

And my CSS is this:

```
div._progress{
    background-color: black;
    width: 100%;
    height: 20px;
    padding: 1px;
  }
  div.progress{
    background-color: green;
    border-radius: 25%;
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    -webkit-transition:width 350ms ease-in-out, height 350ms ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition:width 350ms ease-in-out, height 350ms ease-in-out;
    -o-transition:width 350ms ease-in-out, height 350ms ease-in-out;
    transition:width 350ms ease-in-out, height 350ms ease-in-out;
  }
```

From my javascript I change the width size with document.getElementById......

How can I change the color of the progress for example when the inside bar is the 90% of the container width to red?

Something like this

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Not with CSS.... **NO**.

Comment: can you add you JS code ?

Comment: As you change the width in JS, just change the background-color at the same when it gets over a certain value.

Answer (score 1):

you can use linear gradient property. not necessary to do in js.

```css
#grad1 {
  height: 20px;
  background: linear-gradient(to left, #FF5733 30%, #36FF33 30%, #36FF33 100%);
}
```

```html
<div id="grad1"></div>
```

Comment: But, if the bar is 30% of width, this complete gradient is apply to this 30%. no?